# How to manage the instance of a sub BLoC

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-bloc

I'm create an online shop with 5 main categories. In each category, I have a dynamic number of genres. In each genre, I have a dynamic number of session (shop). In each shop, I have a dynamic number of items.

My UI structure:

```
|Genre 1|GENRE 2|Genre 3|Genre 4|Ge| => Scrollable
|==================================| `
|Session 1 (Shop 1)                | |
|   #==#    #==#    #==#    #==#   | |
|   ||||    ||||    ||||    ||||   | |
|   #==#    #==#    #==#    #==#   | |
|   item    item    item    item   | |
|                                  | |
|Session 2 (Shop 2)                | |
|   #==#    #==#    #==#    #==#   |  } => Scrollable
|   ||||    ||||    ||||    ||||   | |
|   #==#    #==#    #==#    #==#   | |
|   item    item    item    item   | |
|                                  | |
|Session 3 (Shop 3)                | |
|   #==#    #==#    #==#    #==#   | |
|   ||||    ||||    ||||    ||||   | |
|   #==#    #==#    #==#    #==#   | ,
|----------------------------------|
|CATE 1|Cate 2|Cate 3|Cate 4|Cate 5|
+======+======+======+======+======+
```

My BLoC structure:

```
+CategoryBloc<List<GenreModel>>
  +GenreBloc<List<SessionModel>>
     +SessionBloc<List<ContentModel>>
```

The instance of GenreBloc are depended on the current value provided from CategoryBloc. When user delete genre, the GenreBloc and following SessionBloc should be released.

I wonder how to manage the instance of a sub BLoC?

- Where should I create the new instance of GenreBloc?
- Where should I store GenreBlocs?
- When should I release GenreBloc? (call `stream.close()`)